# How to change StatusBar Colour in Android platform in ionic?

Tags: android, ionic-framework, statusbar, ngcordova

My question is how to change StatusBar colour in android platform in ionic?

I've tried many workarounds but none helped to achieve my requirement.

I've installed this plugin [Cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar)

Below is my code:

```html
angular.module('starter', ['starter.controller','ionic', 'starter.services','ngCordova'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaStatusbar) {
    if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
    }

    $cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(false);
    $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#ABCDEF');

    if(window.Connection) {
        if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
            $ionicPopup.confirm({
                title: "Internet Disconnected",
                content: "The internet is disconnected on your device."
            })
            .then(function(result) {
                if(!result) {
                    ionic.Platform.exitApp();
                }
            });
        }
    }

  });
})
```

And set in **config.xml** file Two preference.

```
> <preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
> <preference name="StatusBarBackgroundColor" value="#000000" />
```

Comment: refer this link https://bangaloreionicdeveloper.wordpress.com/2016/06/12/how-to-add-status-bar-color-to-ionic-app/

Comment: @AmruthLS thanks bro but its not working

Answer (score 1):

I use this configuration and it works.

`$cordovaStatusbar.overlaysWebView(true);
 $cordovaStatusbar.styleHex('#ABCDEF');
 $cordovaStatusbar.show();`